# Common parent view in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, uiview

Given an arbitrary set of 2 or more views (`UIView`), I want to determine what is the (closest) common parent for those views. What is the most efficient algorithm for this in Swift?

Based on these hierarchies:

```
                    ┌─────┐                                                  
                    │  A  │                                                  
                    └─────┘                                                  
                       ▲                                                     
          ┌────────────┴────────────┐                                        
          │                         │                                        
       ┌─────┐                   ┌─────┐                ┌─────┐              
       │  B  │                   │  C  │                │  X  │              
       └─────┘                   └─────┘                └─────┘              
          ▲                         ▲                      ▲                 
   ┌──────┴──────┐           ┌──────┴──────┐               │                 
   │             │           │             │               │                 
┌─────┐       ┌─────┐     ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐         ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│  D  │       │  E  │     │  F  │       │  G  │         │  Y  │       │  Z  │
└─────┘       └─────┘     └─────┘       └─────┘         └─────┘       └─────┘
```

- If no views provided, return nil.
- If 1 view provided, return `superview` or nil.
- If any view does not have a `superview` (e.g. "A", "X" or "Z"), return nil.
- If views do not belong to the same hierarchy (e.g. "A" or "X" hierarchy), return nil.

Examples:

```
// no views
[].commonParent()      // nil
// 1 view
[D].commonParent()     // B
// siblings
[D,E].commonParent()   // B
// child/parent
[D,B].commonParent()   // A
// cousins
[D,F].commonParent()   // A
// > 2 views
[D,E,F].commonParent() // A
// with root view
[D,A].commonParent()   // nil
// unrelated hierarchies
[D,Y].commonParent()   // nil
// unrelated view
[D,Z].commonParent()   // nil
```

Comment: Yes, `UIView`. Though the same would apply to NSView.

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking for an algorithm using Swift (i.e. and not Objective-C). To my knowledge there's nothing in UIKit that would help in determining a common parent view.

Comment: Why not Objective-C? Since it's about UIKit, similar approach can be done. UIView has a method `isDescendantOfView:` which can be used for that. So iterates/while through the `superView` of first view, check if the other one is descendant.

Comment: @Larme Swift has `isDescendant` method `subview.isDescendant(of: self.view)`

Comment: Thanks @Larme! I incorporated your suggestion in my answer. "Why not Objective-C?": because I code in Swift and the idiomatic differences between it and Obj-C are significant -- e.g. constrained extensions, higher order functions and optionals to name a few, as shown in example below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Larme's suggestion, here is what I've come up with. Should cover all cases. Comments appreciated.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element:UIView {    
    
    func commonParent() -> UIView? {
        
        // Must be at least 1 view
        guard let firstView = self.first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // If only 1 view, return it's superview, or nil if already root
        guard self.count > 1 else {
            return firstView.superview
        }
        
        // Find the common parent
        var parent = firstView.superview
        let otherItems = dropFirst()
        while parent != nil {
            if otherItems.contains(where:{ !$0.isDescendant(of:parent!) || $0 == parent! }) {
                // Go to next super view and test that
                parent = parent?.superview
            } else {
                // All (other) items are descendants of the first item's
                // super item so return it – it's the common parent.
                return parent
            }
        }
        // else, there is no common parent
        return nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed `reduce()` to `contains()` which is short circuiting to make this a little faster.

Comment: I have tested the performance of this, and it is very fast. (Using >10 nodes, performed 10,000 queries = 0.022 seconds.)

Comment: where do you have parent declared. When I try to run your code it shows an error because parent isn't declared.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is old, but I heard about this interview question and did some searching to see how it's set up, and found this. For those that come here after me, I feel it's important to let you know the current solution is not efficient, O(n^2). You will not pass a tech interview with that. I did it here in objective-c, but it should be straight forward to anyone doing Swift. The idea is to use memoization to keep you from having to search 'n' elements 'm' times, resulting in a O(n). Happy hunting!

```
- (UIView *)commonParentIn:(UIView *)v1 view:(UIView *)v2 {
    // key all parent views of one view
    NSMutableSet *parentSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    while (v2) {
        [parentSet addObject:v2];
        v2 = [v2 superview];
    }

    // search for all parent views of other view in set and return first found
    while (v1) {
        if ([parentSet containsObject:v1]) {
            return v1;
        }
        v1 = [v1 superview];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v4 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v5 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v6 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v7 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v8 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v9 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v10 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v11 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *singleParent = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *onlyChild = [[UIView alloc] init];

[v1 addSubview:v2];
[v1 addSubview:v3];
[v1 addSubview:v4];
[v2 addSubview:v5];
[v2 addSubview:v9];
[v5 addSubview:v6];
[v5 addSubview:v10];
[v10 addSubview:v11];
[v4 addSubview:v7];
[v4 addSubview:v8];
[singleParent addSubview:onlyChild];

UIView *found = [self commonParentIn:v11 view:onlyChild];
```

It helps to draw a tree of the views, that way you know when and where they should have a shared parent view. Then, just change the passed in views for testing.

Comment: Unfortunately doing `[parentSet containsObject:v1]` inside the `while` block makes this a O(n^2).

For O(n), you will have to memoize both super views, then loop both the arrays simultaneously, the view after which they diverge is the common parent.